# Encrypting password for C# configuration file

Tags: c#, encryption, configuration-files, password-protection, password-encryption

I'm trying to figure out the best way to encrypt a password that is in a configuration file.  We are not allowed to hard code the passwords.

This a requirement that I have to meet.

I'm using DOTNET core and this needs to work on windows 10, windows server and OSX.

Does anyone have any good ways of meeting this requirement?

Thank you

Comment: normally for your development and test environment you have a password, but for production you have another password depending on how you deploy and where you deploy. there are various ways to config file transformation. it is too board area search for configuration file transformation

Comment: How would you store them for production?

Comment: i am just givning example but this can be done many ways, like in Azure you can put your password as variable that overwrite when you deploy, I used aslo Octopus that have the password in safe enviromnet, and when we deploy it will automatically overwrite the password or what ever secret to config file. this way developer does not have access to passwords and only deploy managers

Comment: I am not say use Azure, but read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure for inspiration there are different devops tools to research

Comment: Have you thought it true?  When you encrypt that password you need another password (key) to do so. And store that so that the App can decrypt the first.  Want to encrypt the second key too?

Comment: If you were Windows only, I'd suggest using RSA Key Containers for key management. I have no clue if OSX provides a similar capability that can be used using the Core `RSA` class. If it does, let me know (comment with me name in it), and I'll describe a way that should work. As the saying goes, encryption is easy, key management is a PITA.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have made that point but I have a requirement to encrypt the password. As long as the password is encrypted everyone is happy. I made the point that at the end of the day the program needs the plain text password. So to me, this is nothing more than security through obscurity. At the end of the day, I have to compile with the requirement.

Comment: @Flydog57 I think OSX does do that but for me as long as it runs on windows with a 2048 bit key I don't care about MACs (LOL). The code will run on windows at the end of the day anyway. I would to hear anything you have to share. Thank you,

Comment: Windows has a Credential manager built in. Accessible through the DPAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read up on RSA Key Containers. You are going to have your operations group create one for each of your environments. They will *export* them and keep track of the exports for you. They'll also ACL them so that devs have access to them in lower environments, but only ops folks have access in higher environments. They also need to add an ACL so that the process identities on your servers have access.

Those Key Containers will be imported on to the servers, and on any client machines that will be doing any encryption work.

Then create a C# class that has the secret name, perhaps an encryption timestamp, and two strings, one for the clear text secret, and one for the encrypted version.  Make everything JSON serializable.  Mark the clear text member so that it doesn't serialize.

Create a small client app (say, with WinForms) that can read in a collection of secrets objects, decrypting any encrypted text using a key in the Key Container. The app will allow users to paste in a secret (perhaps one copied from KeePass). When the file is saved, the clear text/pasted in secret is encrypted and serialized out. The clear text version is thrown away.

At that point, you have a JSON text file that contains one or more encrypted secrets, but those secrets can only be decrypted by processes running with a token that has access to the RSA Key Container. So, you can put the file in source control and rely on your build/deploy to push the file(s) out to your servers.

Sorry for the lack of code, but I really can't copy/paste code I wrote for my employer. There should be enough here to get you started.